# Something similar to /dev/urandom with configurable seed?

Tags: linux

I'm `dd`'ing from `/dev/urandom` in order to create files with random contents. This works well, but I would like to be able to reproduce the file contents at some later point by running the PRNG again with the same seed. Is there any seedable PRNG which exposes a character device?

I'm using recent Linux 3.X kernels.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Language shouldn't really be relevant as I am looking for a device file, but I plan on running the dd command from bash! If there is a language dependent solution, I would prefer C or Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/urandom` is designed to be as unpredictable as possible. It sounds like you want a more conventional seeded pseudorandom number generator.

Here's one I just wrote in C:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *endptr;
    unsigned long int seed;

    if (argc != 2 || *argv[1] == '\0') {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s seed\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    errno = 0;
    seed = strtoul(argv[1], &endptr, 0);
    if (errno != 0 || *endptr != '\0' || seed > UINT_MAX) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: invalid seed\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    srandom((unsigned int) seed);

    while (1) {
        int i;
        long int randomnum = random();
        for (i = 0; i < sizeof randomnum; i++) {
            if (putchar((randomnum >> (i * CHAR_BIT)) & UCHAR_MAX) == EOF) {
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a program, not a device file, but its output is the same format as you'd get from `/dev/urandom`. You can pipe the output from it into `dd` and omit `if`.

If you need to come up with a truly random seed to supply to the program, you can get one in bash from `/dev/urandom` like this:

```bsh
seed=$(od -vAn -N4 -tu4 </dev/urandom)
```

Replace 4 with whatever `sizeof(unsigned int)` is on your machine (it's probably 4).

Answer (score 2):

**Python 3.9 `random.randbytes` + `random.seed`**

I've learnt to stop fighting what Bash can't do and just go with the flow:

```
randbytes() (
  python -c 'import random;import sys;random.seed(int(sys.argv[1]));sys.stdout.buffer.write(random.randbytes(int(sys.argv[2])))' "$@"
)
```

Usage:

```
randbytes <seed> <nbytes>
```

e.g.:

```
randbytes 0 8 | hd
```

always outputs 8 identical pseudo-random bytes with seed 0:

```
00000000  cd 07 2c d8 be 6f 9f 62                           |..,..o.b|
00000008
```

Readable multiline version at: [Generating random string of seedable data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329381/generating-random-string-of-seedable-data/66018128#66018128)

On my Lenovo ThinkPad P51, I can dump 100 million bytes in ramfs in 0.5s. however, if I try to dump 1 billion it blows up with:

```
Python int too large to convert to C int
```

so it is something to keep in mind.

For comparison:

```
time sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=ramfs/test bs=4k count=24414
```

took 2.5s, so it is slower, which is not surprising as it is a more random source, while the Python generator is deterministic and appears to be written in C.

Tested on Ubuntu 20.10, Linux kernel 5.8.0.

Answer (score 1):

taken from urandom [documentation](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl4_urandom.htm)

> When a Linux system starts up without much operator interaction, the
>   entropy pool may be in a fairly predictable state. This reduces the
>   actual amount of noise in the entropy pool below the estimate. In
>   order to counteract this effect, it helps to carry entropy pool
>   information across shut-downs and start-ups. To do this, add the
>   following lines to an appropriate script which is run during the Linux
>   system start-up sequence:
>
> ```
>     echo "Initializing kernel random number generator..."
>     # Initialize kernel random number generator with random seed 
>     # from last shut-down (or start-up) to this start-up.  Load and 
>     # then save 512 bytes, which is the size of the entropy pool.
>     if [ -f /var/random-seed ]; then
>             cat /var/random-seed >/dev/urandom
>     fi
>     dd if=/dev/urandom of=/var/random-seed count=1
> ```

Comment: I don't think this gets you the same sequence of numbers. It's just a technique to preserve entropy.

Comment: @Taymon , that's the about about how to do it: you can write to /dev/urandoom to set the entropy pool, so you should be able to restore the status of the random source when you need.

Comment: My understanding is that writing to /dev/urandom adds to the entropy pool; it doesn't overwrite whatever was already there.

Comment: then why should you save it when powering it off? In the page that I linked, it's the part of the script just beneath the lines that I posted.

Answer (score 1):

/dev/*random do not use a seed, because they're not pseudo-random number generators. They provide randomness from the environment (using even hardware as a source, like keyboard, interrupts, network, etc.) In the case of /dev/urandom, a seed and an RNG is only used when the pool is exhausted. But it's still unpredictable when that happens.

So, do not read random numbers from /dev/*random. Instead, use the bash facilities to generate random numbers:

```
#! /bin/bash

# Seed the RNG
RANDOM = 1234

# Print 10 random numbers
for i in {1..10}
do
    echo $RANDOM
done
```

The above script will print the same sequence of numbers every time, because the seed is constant.

If you want to generate bytes, meaning values in the range of 0 to 255, then use `printf` instead of `echo` and cycle the random number you get to that range:

```
printf "\\x$(printf "%x" $(($RANDOM % 256)))"
```

If you now run the script and redirect output to a file, it will contain 10 "random" bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your files to be random but reproductible given a seed, you are using the wrong tool. /dev/urandom gets its randomness from the environment (timing of incoming and outgoing network packets, disk accesses, etc.) so even if you start with the same seed, it's very highly unlikely that you will get the same sequence of random numbers two times in a row.

You want a conventional (aka software-only) pseudo-random number generator. The [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) is a good one. It should have an [implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister#Implementations_in_various_languages) in the language you're using. Or just use whatever pseudo-random number generator comes with your language.

Comment: Yes, I might have formulated myself clumsily. What I meant by "urandom-like" was that the PRNG should expose a character device. I am currently using the Mersenne Twister in Python, and it produces satisfactory data, but with an unsatisfactory interface (not a device file ;).

Comment: @Jonatan Why do you want / need a character device interface? What difference will it make to your program? (Just trying to understand your use case.) The Linux kernel itself doesn't export a PRNG through a character device, as far as I know. So any PRNG through a character device would have to be implemented by another userspace program. Calling it through a character device would just add unnecessary round trips through the kernel, as far as I can see now.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ISO C rand() and srand() functions:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html