# Generating random string of seedable data

Tags: python, random

I'm looking for a way to generate a random string of *n* bytes in Python in a similar way to `os.urandom()` method except providing a way to seed the data generation.

So far I have:

```
def genRandData(size):
    buf = chr(random.randint(0,255))
    for i in range(size-1):
        buf = buf + chr(random.randint(0,255))
    return str(buf)
```

However this function is very slow, generating a megabyte of data takes about 1.8 seconds on my machine. Is there any way of improving this (or alternatively a way to seed os.urandom).

Comment: FWIW, `urandom` derives its randomness from random system noise (see [the Linux man page for urandom](http://linux.die.net/man/4/urandom)), so it doesn't make sense to allow it to be seedable. The lack of seedability is annoying for testing things, but OTOH it makes it a useful source of randomness for cryptographic purposes. I guess that's not really relevant for your question, but at least it explains why there isn't a way to seed it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER**

After re-reading OP's question, I understand now that it's about raw bytes, not ascii chars string

So, how about this?

```
import random
gl = 0
def randBytes(size):
    global gl
    nr = bytearray(random.getrandbits(8) for _ in xrange(size))
    gl = nr
    return

%timeit randBytes(1000000)
1 loops, best of 3: 262 ms per loop

In [27]: gl.__sizeof__()
Out[27]: 1087223
```

**OLD ANSWER HERE**

```
import random
import string
def generateRandomString(size):
    return(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(size)))
```

Notes:

One ascii character is 1 byte. So "size" denotes both length of string and size in bytes.

You can use string.ascii_uppercase or ascii_lowercase to have either lower and uppercase

random.seed can be used to specify the seed.

> random.seed([x])¶
>
> Initialize the basic random number generator. Optional argument x can
>   be any hashable object. If x is omitted or None, current system time
>   is used; current system time is also used to initialize the generator
>   when the module is first imported. If randomness sources are provided
>   by the operating system, they are used instead of the system time (see
>   the os.urandom() function for details on availability).

So you could have:

```
    import random
    import string
    def generateRandomString(size, seed=None):
        if seed != None:
             random.seed(seed)
        return(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(size)))
```

Timings:

```
In [30]: %time generateRandomString(1000000)
Wall time: 554 ms
<and then output>
```

Comment: 1) The OP wants all possible byte values from `\x00` to `\xff`, not just letters. 2) It's more efficient to use `.join()` on a list comprehension than on a generator expression, since `.join()` has to scan the strings it's joining twice: the 1st time to determine the total length, the 2nd time to copy the strings to the destination buffer. For details, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/4014959) by Python core developer Raymond Hettinger.

Comment: Hm, right. Did not read that correctly. Just provided a new answer!

Comment: Wow, using `getrandbits` is definitely faster than my solution. But why are you doing that stuff with globals?

Comment: Just wanted to be able to check the length and contents after the function's done. Shouldn't affect performance per se

Comment: They added a method with the same name `randbytes` to 3.9 now BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66018128/895245

Answer (score 3):

If you have `numpy` available, it has a version of the `random` module as `numpy.random` that contains this function that you might consider:

```
numpy.random.bytes(length)
```

It is very fast:

```
$ python -mtimeit "import numpy" "numpy.random.bytes(1<<30)"
10 loops, best of 3: 2.19 sec per loop
```

That's for 1GiB.

And you can seed it with `numpy.random.seed`.

Answer (score 1):

**Python 3.9 `random.randbytes` + `random.seed`**

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/random.html#random.randbytes

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
import sys
random.seed(0)
sys.stdout.buffer.write(random.randbytes(8))
```

writes 8 pseudorandom bytes to stdout with fixed seed of 0:

```
./main.py | hd
```

outputs:

```
00000000  cd 07 2c d8 be 6f 9f 62                           |..,..o.b|
00000008
```

Its [definition in CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.0/Lib/random.py#L283) is simply:

```
    def randbytes(self, n):
        """Generate n random bytes."""
        return self.getrandbits(n * 8).to_bytes(n, 'little')
```

Here it is converted to a Bash one liner and benchmarked compared to `/dev/urandom`: [Something similar to /dev/urandom with configurable seed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861260/something-similar-to-dev-urandom-with-configurable-seed/66018273#66018273)

Answer (score 0):

As Dan D. says, letting `numpy` generate your bytes in one hit at C speed is going to be *way* faster than producing them one at a time at Python speed.

However, if you don't want to use `numpy` you can make your code a little more efficient.

Building a string by concatenation eg `buf = buf + chr(random.randint(0,255))` is very slow, since a new `buf` has to be allocated on every loop (remember, Python strings are immutable). The usual technique in Python for building a string from substrings is to accumulate the substrings in a list then to use the `str.join()` method to combine them in one go.

We can also save a little bit of time by pre-generating a list of our 1 byte strings rather than calling `chr()` for every byte we want.

```
from random import seed, choice

allbytes = [chr(i) for i in range(256)]

def random_bytes(n):
    bytes = []
    for _ in range(n):
        bytes.append(choice(allbytes))
    return ''.join(bytes)
```

We can streamline this and make it *slightly* more efficient by using a list comprehension:

```
def random_bytes(n):
    return ''.join([choice(allbytes) for _ in range(n)])
```

---

Depending on how you intend to use these random bytes, you may find it useful to put them into a [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray) or `bytes` object.

Here's a variant based on cristianmtr's new answer:

```
def random_bytes(n):
    return bytes(bytearray(getrandbits(8) for _ in xrange(n)))
```

You *could* use `str()` in place of `bytes()`, but `bytes()` is better for Python 3, since Python 3 strings are Unicode.